# Error: Document update conflict

Tags: json, macos, unix, terminal, couchdb

When I try to get data from my database I get the following error:

```
{"error":"conflict","reason":"Document update conflict."}
```

Here's my full Terminal.

```
Last login: Thu Feb 13 22:45:22 on ttys000
Idriss-iMac:~ idrisk$ cd Spika-Server
Idriss-iMac:Spika-Server idrisk$ cd install
Idriss-iMac:install idrisk$ curl -X POST http://127.0.0.1:5984/spikademo -  d@designdocuments.dump -H "Content-Type: application/json"
{"error":"conflict","reason":"Document update conflict."}
Idriss-iMac:install idrisk$
```

My database is created an when I type in `http://127.0.0.1:5984/spikademo` in my browser I get the following:

`{"db_name":"spikademo","doc_count":2,"doc_del_count":0,"update_seq":2,"purge_seq":0,"compact_running":false,"disk_size":8290,"data_size":2116,"instance_start_time":"1392349603181164","disk_format_version":6,"committed_update_seq":2}`

Comment: If you are getting data, why are you using POST?

Comment: Should I use GET? @TheDude

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37224834/3405291 "Document conflict error when updating a design document in couchDB
")

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same error while trying to update a doc:

```
$ curl -X PUT http://admin:****@192.168.1.106:5984/sample/doc7 -d @doc7
{"error":"conflict","reason":"Document update conflict."}
```

My `doc7` file looked like this:

```
{
    "name": "David J.",
    "title": "Sir",
}
```

---

To resolve the error, I made a `GET` request first to get the revision number of the doc:

```
$ curl -X GET http://admin:****@192.168.1.106:5984/sample/doc7
{"_id":"doc7","_rev":"2-c703b339b3d4d207d07a082e736ee021","name":"David","title":"Dr"}
```

Then I added the `"_rev":"2-c703b339b3d4d207d07a082e736ee021"` to my `doc7` file like below:

```
{
    "name": "David J.",
    "title": "Sir",
    "_rev":"2-c703b339b3d4d207d07a082e736ee021"
}
```

Now, I can update my doc without any error:

```
$ curl -X PUT http://admin:backpage\ ct@192.168.1.106:5984/sample/doc7 -d @doc7
{"ok":true,"id":"doc7","rev":"3-becda8d4cb81e588ae7125e6a0a372d2"}
```

Notice that after update, CouchDB returns the new revision `rev` of the doc.

---

Looks like you can send a `HEAD` request to get the revision number of the doc, according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37224834/3405291). When I do a `HEAD` request, I need to use the `-I` options of curl and the revision number is returned by `ETag` like below:

```
$ curl -X HEAD http://admin:**@192.168.1.106:5984/sample/doc7  -I
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-CouchDB-Body-Time: 0
X-Couch-Request-ID: 27d4e242fb
Server: CouchDB/2.1.1 (Erlang OTP/18)
ETag: "4-dfd11b5ba753d3b80e522e3b63c0a745"
Date: Tue, 27 Mar 2018 17:11:48 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 121
Cache-Control: must-revalidate
```

Comment: when we use the fauxton, we don't need to provide the rev id, as it automatically update that. I am still hitting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `curl http://127.0.0.1:5984/spikademo` to get the database information.